# What does thing + さまさまだ mean?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

> 大きな声じゃ言えないが爆破解体さまさまだよ

"さまさま" seems to be use to bestow honorific over things and people, however I can't seem to grasp why he'd use it for an explosion?

"I wouldn't say it out loud, but the explosion will be..."

My guess is that he's hyped about the explosion?

Comment: As seen in your sentence, it's important to note that さまさま often conveys a sarcastic or joking nuance, rather than pure respect or gratitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the 様 repeated twice that is normally attached to human names, expressing respect.

さまさま expresses extreme gratitude by the speaker, who receives a large benefit (usually financial) from the object.

爆破解体さまさまだ means (or implies) *I'm rather grateful for the demolishing by explosives*. The context should provide *why*.

---

Other examples may help.

If you were in export industry (e.g. car manufacturers in Japan), you'd say 円安さまさまだ, meaning cheap yen affects your business positively.

Or if you were one of those people who benefited from Covid, you'd say コロナさまさまだ, meaning you are rather grateful for Covid (usually about the money it brought).